# pandas SeriesGroupBy.nlargest duplicates multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have pandas Series
It has MultiIndex with names `user`, `item`:

```py
>>> s
user  item
11    1       0.60
      3       0.46
      4       0.68
      2       0.75
      0       0.05
13    1       0.71
      3       0.82
      4       0.65
      2       0.45
      0       0.16
12    1       0.39
      3       0.06
      4       0.09
      2       0.96
      0       0.97
0     1       0.31
      3       0.27
      4       0.22
      2       0.52
      0       0.06
5     1       0.03
      3       0.47
      4       0.34
```

I want to get 2 largest values for each user. I want result in the same format.

But instead I get duplicated index for `user` when do

```py
>>> s.groupby('user').nlargest(2)
user  user  item
11    11    2       0.75
            4       0.68
13    13    3       0.82
            1       0.71
12    12    0       0.97
            2       0.96
0     0     2       0.52
            1       0.31
5     5     0       0.90
            3       0.47
7     7     1       0.84
            4       0.84
6     6     1       0.91
```

Comment: Try grouping on the index: `s.groupby(level=0).nlargest(2)`

Comment: @coldspeed `level=0` also returns with duplicates

Answer (score 0):

add `group_keys=False`:

```py
>>> s.groupby('user', group_keys=False).nlargest(2)
user  item
11    2       0.75
      4       0.68
13    3       0.82
      1       0.71
12    0       0.97
      2       0.96
0     2       0.52
      1       0.31
5     0       0.90
      3       0.47
```